# При помощи top, показать все процессы запущенные в пространстве ядра

Tags: linux, консоль

Как при помощи top отобразить все процессы, запущенные в пространстве ядра?

Comment: `top` же потоки ядра по умолчанию показывает, не?

Comment: я имею ввиду как отсортировать только процессы пространства ядра и исключить пользовательские

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У всех ядерных процессов один предок - процесс с PID 2.

Чтобы в окне остались только ядерные процессы достаточно произвести следующую последовательность манипуляций:

1. Нажать `O` (латинское O заглавное), задать фильтр `PPID<20` -- в фильтрах используется сравнение строк, поэтому `PPID<3` оставит кучу процессов, у которых PID родителя начинается с 2
2. Нажать `O`, задать фильтр `PPID>1` -- отфильтровать все процессы, унаследованные от родителя с PID 1.
3. У меня по неизвестной причине список процессов криво обновляется после задания фильтров, поэтому мне пришлось делать ещё один шаг. Нажать `f` и в списке колонок добавить PPID.

Вот так выглядит окно `top` на Ubuntu 18 после этих действий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правда, нужно признать, что при этом отфильтровался корневой процесс с PID 2.

Comment: огромное спасибо, очень полезная информация